# Can't Find Pydev in Ecilipse Kepler

Tags: python, pydev

I have installed Pydev in ecilipse kepler but in window->preferences I can't find pydev. Can you please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may not installed Pydev properly that's why you may not find pydev. For install/unintall Pydev in Ecilipse Kepler here is **[reference link](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)** follow it